# Execute batch is not updating the data in SQL table -

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, prepared-statement, jdbctemplate

I am trying to update the table using execute batch. I am not getting any errors. The program is executing successfully however the table is not getting updated with the data. I am not sure what is stopping the update in SQL table. Please help..

```
    PreparedStatement pstmtAssignmentTable = null;
    try {
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        try {
            connection.setAutoCommit(false);
            try {

            String sql_SelectSpecialSPOCInfo = "Select CustomerNumber, U.UserId, U.TeamId, SPOC.EmployeeId, WorkProfileId from admn.SpecialSPOCAssignmentLookUp SPOC join admn.Users U on SPOC.EmployeeID = U.EmployeeID join admn.UserPhone UP on UP.UserID = U.UserID join admn.SpecialCustomerLookUp LLU on LLU.CustomerCode = SPOC.CustomerCode";
            String sql_updateAssignmentTable = "Update asgn.Assignment Set UserId = ?, TeamId = ? , Source = 'Manual Assignment', WorkProfileId = ? , AssignedDate = cast(getdate() as date)  where CustomerNumber = ?";
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(sql_SelectSpecialSPOCInfo);
            ManualAssignmentModel employeeInfo = new ManualAssignmentModel();
            int recordNo = 0;
            int batchSize = 100;
            while (rs.next()) {
                employeeInfo.setCustomerNumber(rs.getString("CustomerNumber"));
                employeeInfo.setUserId(rs.getString("UserId"));
                employeeInfo.setTeamId(rs.getString("TeamId"));
                employeeInfo.setWorkProfileId(rs.getString("WorkProfileId"));
                recordNo++;
                pstmtAssignmentTable = connection.prepareStatement(sql_updateAssignmentTable);
                {
                    pstmtAssignmentTable.setString(1, employeeInfo.getUserId());
                    pstmtAssignmentTable.setString(2, employeeInfo.getTeamId());
                    pstmtAssignmentTable.setString(3, employeeInfo.getWorkProfileId());
                    pstmtAssignmentTable.setString(4, employeeInfo.getCustomerNumber());
                    System.out.println("Adding to Batch ");
                    pstmtAssignmentTable.addBatch();
                }
                if (recordNo == batchSize) {
                    System.out.println(
                            "Batch Limit Reached. Updating the Database with the items added in the current Batch");    
                    pstmtAssignmentTable.executeBatch();
                    System.out.println("Batch execute cpmpleted..");
                    pstmtAssignmentTable.clearBatch();
                    recordNo = 0;
                }

            }
             System.out.println("Record count is less than the Batch Limit. Updating the
             Database with available records...");
             pstmtAssignmentTable.executeBatch();
             System.out.println(" Job Completed");

            } finally {
            if (pstmtAssignmentTable != null) {
                pstmtAssignmentTable.close();
            }
        }
             connection.commit();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            connection.rollback();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: You're recreating the prepared statement on each run of the while loop.

Comment: Yes, but even if I move the prepared statement outside my loop, it is not updating the table....

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of possible causes here:

1. Maybe The select query returns less than 100 rows (int batch=100), so you never enter the if statement ... even if we assume there are more than 100 rows, your code won't excuteBatch for the elements after the last 100 elements (363 rows -> 300rows will be updated, last 63rows the code won't enter the if statement):

   if (recordNo == batchSize) {
   //code
   }
2. In your while statement, you assign pstmtAssignmentTable again, you need to move it outside the while:

   pstmtAssignmentTable = connection.prepareStatement(sql_updateAssignmentTable);
   while (rs.next()) {
   //code
   }

**FIX:**

Here is the code with the mentioned modifications:

```
    PreparedStatement pstmtAssignmentTable = null;
    try {
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        try {
            connection.setAutoCommit(false);
            try {
                String sql_SelectSpecialSPOCInfo = "Select CustomerNumber, U.UserId, U.TeamId, SPOC.EmployeeId, WorkProfileId from admn.SpecialSPOCAssignmentLookUp SPOC join admn.Users U on SPOC.EmployeeID = U.EmployeeID join admn.UserPhone UP on UP.UserID = U.UserID join admn.SpecialCustomerLookUp LLU on LLU.CustomerCode = SPOC.CustomerCode";
                String sql_updateAssignmentTable = "Update asgn.Assignment Set UserId = ?, TeamId = ? , Source = 'Manual Assignment', WorkProfileId = ? , AssignedDate = cast(getdate() as date)  where CustomerNumber = ?";

                //
                String sql_CountSpecialSPOCInfo = "Select COUNT(*) from admn.SpecialSPOCAssignmentLookUp SPOC join admn.Users U on SPOC.EmployeeID = U.EmployeeID join admn.UserPhone UP on UP.UserID = U.UserID join admn.SpecialCustomerLookUp LLU on LLU.CustomerCode = SPOC.CustomerCode";
                ResultSet rsCount = connection.createStatement().executeQuery(sql_CountSpecialSPOCInfo);
                //BE CAREFUL: In Case this throws an exception, maybe we need to use  rsCount.next(); to move to the first row
                int size = rsCount.getInt(1);
                //If the size is less than the batchSize, then we use the size to
                int batchSize = size > 100 ? 100 : size;


                Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(sql_SelectSpecialSPOCInfo);
                ManualAssignmentModel employeeInfo = new ManualAssignmentModel();
                int recordNo = 0;


                pstmtAssignmentTable = connection.prepareStatement(sql_updateAssignmentTable);
                while (rs.next()) {
                    employeeInfo.setCustomerNumber(rs.getString("CustomerNumber"));
                    employeeInfo.setUserId(rs.getString("UserId"));
                    employeeInfo.setTeamId(rs.getString("TeamId"));
                    employeeInfo.setWorkProfileId(rs.getString("WorkProfileId"));
                    recordNo++;

                    pstmtAssignmentTable.setString(1, employeeInfo.getUserId());
                    pstmtAssignmentTable.setString(2, employeeInfo.getTeamId());
                    pstmtAssignmentTable.setString(3, employeeInfo.getWorkProfileId());
                    pstmtAssignmentTable.setString(4, employeeInfo.getCustomerNumber());
                    System.out.println("Adding to Batch ");
                    pstmtAssignmentTable.addBatch();

                    if (recordNo == batchSize) {
                        System.out.println("Batch Limit Reached. Updating the Database with the items added in the current Batch");
                        pstmtAssignmentTable.executeBatch();
                        System.out.println("Batch execute cpmpleted..");
                        pstmtAssignmentTable.clearBatch();
                        recordNo = 0;
                    }

                }

                // We will still need to excuteBatch in case recordNo<batchSize
                if(recordNo>0){
                    System.out.println("Updating the Database with the items added in the current Batch");
                    pstmtAssignmentTable.executeBatch();
                    System.out.println("Batch execute cpmpleted..");
                    pstmtAssignmentTable.clearBatch();
                }

                System.out.println("Record count is less than the Batch Limit. Updating the Database with available records...");
                pstmtAssignmentTable.executeBatch();
                System.out.println(" Job Completed");

            } finally {
                if (pstmtAssignmentTable != null) {
                    pstmtAssignmentTable.close();
                }
            }
            connection.commit();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            connection.rollback();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Please, Share the results, so we can update the answer and make it more generic.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for looking into my program.
1) I have already added the necessary code to take care of records < batch.
I added executebatch() both inside and outside of the while loop. Please check my original code again.
                System.out.println("Record count is less than the Batch Limit. Updating the Database with available records...");
                pstmtAssignmentTable.executeBatch();
2) Writing prepared statement inside while loop is not a great idea as you said but that didn't fix my problem. I moved it outside and data is still not updating the sql table..

Comment: can you please run the count query and share it, so we are sure the select statement return rows

Comment: I am able to fetch the records from count query. Is there anyway I can check what is added in the batch before I execute the batch? I tried toString but that didn't work with prepared statement object. I am able to get the records from select statement but I am not sure if the fetched records are setting to prepared statement to process the update query.  Also, I don't know if the Tables are not getting updated because of variable type mismatch?!.